# Video element in ionic android

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, html5-video

Trying to use video tag in ionic framework.
All thinks are working fine but not able to how can i remove the default play button.

[Video default play button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5g6Ar.jpg)

Note: This play button is only visible in android app not on iOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the poster property?

```
<video width="470" height="255" poster="placeholder.png" controls></video>
```

Comment: Already tried! It will add poster but not able to remove the default poster. The default poster will be there until the custom poster is properly loaded.

Comment: Maybe this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15508421/how-to-fill-video-element-with-poster-image-even-if-the-poster-image-is-a-differ

Comment: Also, I asume you are using Android stock browser. Don't you?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did anybody solve this with pure HTML/CSS? Setting a poster won't work.